# Getting 3 beeps pause 3 beeps continuesly

Tags: boot

Hi I got a asrock h61icafe motherboard with i7 3770 16gb ram Rx 590 but today when I switched on my computer it gives me 3 beeps pause 3beeps continuesly I did everything to fix this removed the ram cleaned it did an CMOS battery reset removed the card and tried on onboard nothing works please help me

Comment: https://www.asrockind.com/en-gb/index.php?route=newsblog/faq&faq_id=60

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/O8s2nOA.png Did you put the RAM in the correct slot(s)? If there is more than one RAM stick, have you tried each one on its own?